# OS X - undoing mkdir followed by mount and another mkdir

Tags: macos, mac, mount

So far I've tried my google fu to figure out exactly what I've done on the terminal (I'm running OS X Yosemite 10.10.3), but I'm not satisfied with my current understanding on how mounting and mount points work on a Macintosh machine... this is pretty much what happened:

I tried to manually install rEFInd per the instructions found here (http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#osx), and so far have done the following on my terminal:

```
:~ felix$ mkdir /Volumes/esp

:~ felix$ sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1/Volumes/esp

:~ felix$ sudo mkdir -p /Volumes/esp/efi/refind
```

My current understanding is that I made a "mount point" inside my local user directory (User "Felix") mounted an msdos type filesystem onto the EFI, and then made a nested directory within the esp folder that I made on the first command. However, I can't find these directories in the felix directory. What did I do? What exactly did I mount, and where did I mount it? Why can't I find /Volumes/esp?

If I want to start over again and reverse all the changes I've made with these three commands, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a space.  The middle command is actually:

```
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/esp
```

This command means "mount the /dev/disk0s1 partition to the directory /Volumes/esp directory (which you created in the previous step), and force it to be an msdos filesystem type"

Since you never accomplished this step, my guess is that the '/dev/disk0s1' partition is not yet mounted.

To undo EVERYTHING:

```
sudo umount /dev/disk0s1/Volumes/esp (no space, and I expect this to fail)
sudo rm -r /Volumes/esp
```

At that point you should be back at the beginning.